# How to update a Screen UI from another Class in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

So i have a Screen, `HomeScreen`. Now i have another class named `LoginUtil` which performs some operation. I am calling its method 'login' from `Homescreen` which works totally fine. But whatever response i get in `LoginUtil` ... i want to access it in `HomeScreen` but i am not sure as to how to do it.

**HomeScreen**

```js
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State < HomeScreen > createState() => HomeScreenState();
}

class HomeScreenState extends State < HomeScreen > {
  var advertisingMessage = "Click here";
  static
  const advertisingUUID = "0000A002-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
  static
  const bleChannel = MethodChannel('ble');
  final LoginUtil loginUtil = LoginUtil();
  var connection = 0;
  var connectionImage =
    "https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_lbmtnnap.json";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    performBleOperations();
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationDrawerWidget(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Home"),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScanScreen()));
            },
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
              child: Image.asset("assets/scanner.png", height: 20, width: 20),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            Text("Connected Devices: 0",
              textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 19)),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    showAdvertisingBottomSheet();
                  },
                  child: Stack(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Lottie.network(connectionImage,
                        height: 180.0, width: 180.0),
                      Text(advertisingMessage)
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("Waiting for a device to connect"),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: const Color(0xFF09419B),
                child: Text("See Logs",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 50, right: 50),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: const Color(0xFF09419B),
                child: Text("Create Downlink",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 50, right: 50),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            ),
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              color: const Color(0xFF09419B),
                child: Text("Track Trips",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, left: 50, right: 50),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("12"), Text("Trucks")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Out For Delivery"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("9"), Text("Trucks")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Idle"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("122"), Text("")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Alerts"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20,
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("1"), Text("Ongoing")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Incoming Trip"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("12"), Text("Ongoing")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Outgoing Trips"),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Card(
                        child: Container(
                          width: 70,
                          height: 70,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [Text("12"), Text("Trucks")],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text("Out For Delivery"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ]),
            ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future < void > performBleOperations() async {

    loginUtil.login("Jack", 18, callback: (String name, int age) {
      // showLoading = false;
      // userInfo = "name: $name, age: $age";
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void updateConnectionState() {
    print("Trying to update the connection state");
    var connectionState = loginUtil.connectionState;
    if (connectionState == 0) {
      setState(() {
        connectionImage =
          "https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_cpjxufjf.json";
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        connectionImage =
          "https://assets3.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_lbmtnnap.json";
      });
    }
  }


}
```

**LoginUtil**

```js
class LoginUtil {
  LoginUtil() {
    _channel.setMethodCallHandler(_methodCallHandler);
  }

  final MethodChannel _channel =
    const MethodChannel('my-channel');
  var connectionState;
  Function(String, int) ? _loginSuccessCallback;

  Future < void > login(String name, int age, {
    Function(String, int) ? callback
  }) async {
    _loginSuccessCallback = callback;
    var params = {
      'name': name,
      'age': age
    };
    // call native method 'login'
    try {
      await _channel.invokeMethod('login', params);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future < dynamic > _methodCallHandler(MethodCall call) async {
    print("Reached here my brother");
    String method = call.method;
    if (method == 'loginSuccess') {
      if (_loginSuccessCallback != null) {
        final map = call.arguments;
        connectionState = map['connectionState'];
        print("Connection state is: $connectionState");
      }
    }
  }

  getCurrentState() {
    print("Returning current state");
    return connectionState;
  }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class will give you clear answer for your question, Here you can access your parent class from your child class

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'main1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Modalbtn(),
  ));
}

class Modalbtn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ModalbtnState createState() => _ModalbtnState();
}

class _ModalbtnState extends State<Modalbtn> {
  String value = "0";
  // Pass this method to the child page.
  void _update(String newValue) {
    setState(() => value = newValue);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                showModalBottomSheet(
                    context: context,
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [StatefulModalbtn(update: _update)],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              iconSize: 20,
            ),
            Text(
              value,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StatefulModalbtn extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<String> update;
  StatefulModalbtn({required this.update});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => update("100"), // Passing value to the parent widget.

      child: Text('Update (in child)'),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand, in this line `onPressed: () => update("100")`, how are you able to call `update` method?

Comment: Yes we can able to call  because we pass the value from the parent class to child class     StatefulModalbtn({required this.update});

Comment: You have a variable named `update`, right? How are you calling a method `update("100")` ?

Comment: void _update(String newValue) {
    setState(() => value = newValue);
  }

Comment: we have _update method in parent class

Comment: we are passing this method on our child widget [StatefulModalbtn(update: _update)],

Comment: So when we acceess the variable in child class it will call the method from the parent class

Comment: How is that even a parent class? What makes it a parent class? You have not even extended any class anywhere.

Comment: Just copy this code and test , You will understand

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242905/discussion-between-anandh-krishnan-and-sagar-balyan).